# How to get cropped select in PDFTron?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdftron

I'm trying to extract cropped portion in pdf in PDFTron. The crop feature creates a new page instead I want to get the cropped image and make send it in a API call in ReactJs.
Can anyone help me in extracting the cropped area.

**EDIT**

I'm trying to get cropped portion of the page, in PDFTron by default it crops the page and creates a new page with the cropped part. I want to get the cropped part of the page in form of an image without creating a new page and make an API call.

OS: Windows

Framework: ReactJS

[image]

[image]

Comment: "The crop feature..." What exactly do you mean by "crop feature"? Can you provide screenshot/url to what you refer to exactly. "...get the cropped image..." you want to get an image of just part of a page? What platform/OS are you trying to do this? Client side in the browser? Using PDFTron WebViewer? Screenshots help a lot in understanding your question.

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks for for the reply I have edited the question please check and let me know if I can get an image from the crop page feature.

Answer (score 1):

We do not have that functionality supported out of the box, but what you could do is build custom button to do something similar. We have an example you might be interested here - https://groups.google.com/g/pdfnet-webviewer/c/kpW94WwAfaA/m/-UAavgReDAAJ. Note that this example is a bit old, so there might have been some API changes since.

Thanks.